# 2D character not moving. Console shows no errors

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, game-development

I couldn't find any mistakes in this code. if there aren't any mistakes in the code, please let me know what's wrong.

````
```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float speed = 5;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
    
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        float h = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float v = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector2 pos = transform.position;

        pos.x += h * Time.deltaTime;
        pos.y += v * Time.deltaTime;

        transform.position = pos;
    }


} // class

```
````

Comment: Have you verified the values of `h` and `v`, and also the amount by which the `pos` coords are being changed?

Comment: Are you sure its not just moving really slowly

Comment: It is probably moving extremely slowly this is because you are getting a low value from Input.GetAxis and then multiplying it by a low value of Time.deltaTime. low value * low value = very low value

Comment: can i please get the correct code to resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

Try putting Horizontal and Vertical values in a `Vector2` Then do `transform.Translate(Movement * speed * Time.deltaTime);` Instead of adding the position. Also you forgot to multiply the position by the speed. The Update should look something like this.

```
        float h = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float v = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector2 Movement = Vector2.zero;
        Movement.y = v;
        Movement.x = h;

        transform.Translate(Movement * speed * Time.deltaTime);
```

Comment: unfortunetly, it didnt work :((

Comment: @ShriyansKumar Hm, that's unfortunate. Make sure the script is attached to the player and try adding an f after the speed value public float speed = 5f and if it still doesn't work try making the value really high to make sure it's not just moving very slow. Also make some objects in the scene so you can tell if you're moving or not.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is that you forgot to include the `speed` multiplier in your code, so the correct code should be this

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float speed = 5;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
    
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float h = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float v = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector2 pos = transform.position;

        pos.x += h * speed * Time.deltaTime; //Multiply h by speed
        pos.y += v * speed * Time.deltaTime; //Multiply v by speed

        transform.position = pos;
    }


} // class
```